# Idiomatic way to prevent a function calling itself in elisp?

Tags: functions

If I have a function which needs to know if it's calling itself, what is an idiomatic way to check for this situation?

While I can always bind a symbol (with a name that's highly likely to be unique) with `let`, then check if it's declared in the outer scope, I'm not sure if this is the best way.

Is there a common convention for handling this case?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: I believe @Basil answered the question. But I think it might help if you added an example use case - e.g., show why you want a function to know if its current invocation is a recursive (or an iterated) one.

Answer (score 2):

One common way to detect recursion without using a global variable is the use of an optional argument:

```el
(defun foo (x &optional recursed)
  "Frobnicate X."
  (unless recursed
    (foo x t)))
```

You could even hide the optional argument from the function's API:

```el
(defun foo (x &optional recursed)
  "Frobnicate X."
  (declare (advertised-calling-convention (x) "1.0.0"))
  (unless recursed
    (foo x t)))
```

or:

```el
(defun foo (x &optional recursed)
  "Frobnicate X.
\n(fn X)"
  (unless recursed
    (foo x t)))
```

(See [`(info "(elisp) Function Documentation")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Documentation.html).)

Another way is to create a closure:

```el
(defalias 'foo
  (let (recursed)
    (lambda (x)
      (unless recursed
        (setq recursed t)
        (foo x))))
  "Frobnicate X.")
```

Of course, there's nothing wrong with using a dynamic variable instead, depending on your needs.  For example, the built-in `lisp/net/shr.el` HTML renderer uses a counter variable that it increments with each recursive call to `shr-descend`.

If you're looking for something more complicated than just guarding against recursion, then you may want to look at how `called-interactively-p` uses `backtrace-frame`, or `mapbacktrace`.

Comment: I can't use the calling convention method, as I don't have a lot of control of who is calling what/when. Could you show how the `foo` alias would be used?

Comment: @ideasman42 The closure is like any old `defun`, except `recursed` is `nil` only the first time it is called. You can try calling it for any value `X` as `(foo X)`.